# Affine Rotation Matrices

Tags: c++, math, matrix, affinetransform

I'm writing a Matrix class that has static `RotationX()` `RotationY()` and `RotationZ()` methods in C++. If I multiply the matrices together before multiplying by the vector, I get different results than if I had multiplied the matrices individually to the vector.

This code

```
Vec4 result1 { 1, 1, 1, 1 };
result1 = Matrix::RotationX(ToRadians(-90)) * result1;
result1 = Matrix::RotationY(ToRadians(90)) * result1;
result1 = Matrix::RotationZ(ToRadians(90)) * result1;
// result1 => { -1, -1, -1, 1 }
```

gives different results than this code

```
Vec4 result2 { 1, 1, 1, 1 };
auto rotation = Matrix::RotationX(ToRadians(-90)) *
                Matrix::RotationY(ToRadians(90)) *
                Matrix::RotationZ(ToRadians(90));
result2 = rotation * result2;
// result2 => { 1, 1, -1, 1 }
```

What is the issue here? I can provide my rotation function implementations, but I wanted to make sure this wasn't a conceptual issue with affine transformations before posting code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example corresponds to the reverse order of matrix multiplication. Compare:

```
Z * (Y * (X * V))
((X * Y) * Z) * V
```

But matrix multiplication is not commutative!

Comment: I had not realized the order of my matrices were different :) Thank you